# Why does my merge sort code not giving me desired results? what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

My merge sort code is giving some Weird results.
that is:
4201675 7257888 7209152 23490 7257888 7257888 6.

I am not able to find any bug as it is compiling and giving results by not what i want.
it should sort the given array.

All possible bugs suggested by vsoce is fixed me. Is there anything wrong with dynamic allocation of array.
can anyone please help me with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int si, int ei){
    int size = ei - si + 1;
    int mid = (ei + si) / 2;

    int *out = new int[size];
    int i = si, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    while(i<=mid && j<=ei){
        if(arr[i]<=arr[j]){
            out[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            out[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }        
    }
    while(i<=mid){
        out[k] = arr[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j<=ei){
        out[k] = arr[i];
        k++;
        j++;
    }

    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <=ei;i++){
        arr[i] = out[m];
        m++;
    }

    delete[] out;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[],int si,int ei){
    if(si>=ei){
        return;
    }

    int mid = (ei + si) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, si, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ei);
    merge(arr, si, ei);
}

int main(){

    int arr[] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    mergeSort(arr, 0, 6);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by debugging a small failing example. Can be done with pen and paper and some printf statements to see what happens.

Comment: `ei` starts out with 6, which is one past the end of `arr`. You should not try to access `arr[ei]`. But `merge` does just that (`j<=ei, arr[j]`).

Comment: same for `for (int i = 0; i <= 6;i++){` - you started with six numbers, this loop tries to print 7

Comment: You may want to clarify for yourself what the functions are supposed to do with their arguments - are the bounds inclusive/exclusive? And then revise the code according to that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, But i figured it out and you solution was not correct. But again Thanks. It should i=si, in last for loop in merge funtion, that is it.

Comment: `int m = 0;
    for (int x = si; x <= ei;x++){
        arr[x] = out[m];
        m++;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and you solution was not correct. But again Thanks. It should i=si, in last for loop in merge funtion, that is it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[],int si,int ei){

    int size = ei - si + 1;
    int mid = (ei + si) / 2;
    int *out = new int[size];

    int k = 0, i = si, j = mid + 1;
    while(i<=mid && j<=ei){
        if(arr[i]<=arr[j]){
            out[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            out[k] = arr[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    while(i<=mid){
        out[k] = arr[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j<=ei){
        out[k] = arr[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }

    int m = 0;
    for (int x = si; x <= ei;x++){
        arr[x] = out[m];
        m++;
    }

    delete[] out;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[],int si,int ei){
    if(si>=ei){
        return;
    }
    int mid = (ei + si) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, si, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ei);

    merge(arr, si, ei);
}

int main(){

    int arr[] = {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    mergeSort(arr, 0, 6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

        return 0;
}
```